# Alter details (organization, city etc.) of upload key/keystore for Play Store

Tags: android, google-play, certificate, android-keystore

I have generated an upload key and keystore for my app. I followed this [guidance](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#generate-key).

I have not yet created a production release, and my app has not yet been through the review process. I have uploaded and created some test releases.

I would like to alter the details on my key: *Organization*, *City*, etc.

Can I alter the details of an existing key, or can I create and use a new key for my app?

Thanks.